# Express passport middleware not woriking with get request params

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I'm building a webserver with node, express, jwt and passport. But when I try to have a route with a get methode:

```
app.get('/api/:key/lights', passport.authenticate("jwt", {session: false}), function(req, res) {
if (yubiAtHome) {
var sKey = req.params.key;
dbController.checkApiKey(sKey, function(err, bData) {
  if (bData.status) {
    hueController.getLights(function(err, jData) {
      if (err) {
        generateResponse(res, 'get Lights', null, err, 'lLights', 500);
      } else {
        generateResponse(res, 'get Lights', jData, null, 'lLights', 200);
      }
    });
  } else {
     generateResponse(res, 'api key not valid', bData, 'apikey invalid', 'lLights', 500);
     }
    });
   } else {
      generateResponse(res, 'yub not pressent', null, 'yub not pressent', 'lLights', 500);
  }
});
```

But this route do not work for some reason, if I remove the `passport.authenticate("jwt", {session: false})` or remove the params ( the ":key") it works, but otherwise it do not and returns a 401:Unauthorized. How can this be ?

**EDIT**

This is how I try to access the route: 
[image: Postman of the route]

Comment: if it doesnt work with passport middleware, maybe you have an auth problem. And if it doesnt work with a certain url pattern, make sure you try with this pattern and make sure you dont have any other route that could match this pattern BEFORE this controller.

Comment: I've check it all, and I only have a route that has a param more on the route. And my default route `app.get('/', passport.authenticate("jwt", {
  session: false
}), function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});` is working..

Comment: Could you show us, how are you trying to access this route? (e.g as postman or testcase or via browser... anything)

Comment: @LeandroRodrigues updated the question.

Comment: Hm.. So, if you remove the ':key' from your route, and it became just `/api/lights`. And if you send `http://localhost/api/lights` does it work?

Comment: Actually it doesn't, but the root route, "/" works with passport..

Comment: Could you provide your `/` route?

Comment: It's the route in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the quotation marks from the header `Authorization`.

Im my test here, when I put the quotation marks, it doesn't work.

Ex:

Authorization rather than 'Authorization'

Comment: Tried it, didn't do anything.. :-\

Comment: Look, in you postman example, you are using the header: `Authentication`, but the correct is `Authorization`. Did you try to change it?

Comment: Oh for .... omg, that's just a silly mistake.. omg.. Thanks for spotting that stupid error..